# Business case or something specific?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a use case where I am *approximating a function given its integral and "shape"*.  The use case is being provided a distribution function (representing a work schedule) approximate it to a given integral.

I have a piece of code that does this, but I'm unsure of how to refer to it mathematically, provided description aside. Is there a broader topic at hand that does something I'm not seeing/understanding at scale?

While the method approximates to a comfortable level, I'm annoyed that I can't put a name to what I'm doing, and would like to ensure I better understand the topic-- even if the answer is this is just a random business case. I've taken Calc I.

Comment: Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, you can take the derivative of the integral to find the original function, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: My impression was that the integral was only known numerically, so the derivative could only be calculated numerically, and maybe the worry is that "derivative" is the wrong word in such cases. I think it's fine, but of course it's necessary to explain the approximation being made (step function derivative between successive known points? Derivative of a spline fit?)

Comment: The derivative is useful in this case, but not the goal.

Comment: You have some code that you hope does something of interest to you. You would like us to help you check a technique you use in that code. You need to provide more information about what you want to achieve and how you tried to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, if you know the integral of a function is, say, $F(x)$ that is to say:
$$F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$
and from FTC it follows that:
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x)$$

---

In terms of working it out from several values of the integrals, there are a few ways to do it. Lets say:
$$F(x_1)=y_1\\F(x_2)=y_2\\\text{etc}$$
then there are several ways to approximate the derivative at a given position:
$$g(x+h)\approx g(x)+hg'(x)$$
$$g'(x)\approx\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
so in your case:
$$f(x)\approx\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$
then use something like regression. Since you said you know the "shape" you can make assumptions about what kind of function it is (polynomial, exponential, sinusoidal etc.)

Comment: I think seeing it like this was what I needed to see-- thank you, Henry.